# ffmpeg Not converting some mov videos to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert videos, command works fine for all videos format including mov but it not converting some mov videos,i don't understand is it problem in mov video? although that video playing good on player The commands which i am trying :

```
$command = "$ffmpeg_path -i $video_path -acodec copy -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f mp4 -s 858x480 $mobile_video.mp4";
```

OR

```
$command="$ffmpeg_path -i $video_path -codec:v libx264 -preset slow -b:v 550k -maxrate 550k -bufsize 1100k -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k $mobile_video.mp4";
```

OR

```
$command="$ffmpeg_path -i $video_path -vcodec copy -acodec copy $mobile_video.mp4";
```

I try all these commands but some mov videos not converted to mp4

Comment: I'm calling offtopic. This isn't really about php, or programming, and more how to use ffmpeg. We're not general software tech support.

Comment: To increase the chances for finding the problem a little bit, append `2>&1` to the command. This will [redirect stderr to stdout](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/), the latter being the only stream redirected/fetched by the php exec functions.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting comment because there was an entire discussion (and possible answer) here: 
[ffmpeg convert mov file to mp4 for HTML5 video tag IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524776/ffmpeg-convert-mov-file-to-mp4-for-html5-video-tag-ie9)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac -strict experimental output.mp4
```